# How can I get notifications in VS Code like in Google Colab when a Jupyter Notebook Cell is done executing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to receive notifications about completed cells in VS Code like in Google Colab. How I can do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From googling "`github jupyter issues notification cell done`", I found [Kernel finished running cells notification #5654](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5654). [Quoting @roblourens](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5654#event-8008363741):

> We recently added Audio Cues for when cells finished running, check it out, it might help. I don't think we will add a vscode notification for this, but this might be enabled with extension API in the future.

The issue ticket is closed as `out-of-scope`.

Another user mentioned that they use a workaround of making the cell run code at the end to play a sound (`winsound.Beep`) ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5654#issuecomment-1008446528)).